# Grab Spreadsheet names then read each in Foreach

Tags: c#, excel

Ok, I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this in code. I have a spreadsheet with numerous tabs and what I want to do is in C# read the name of each sheet and then its corresponding rows of data. Currently, this is what I have:

```
            if (!DirectoryIsEmpty(DropZone.ToString())) 
        { 

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DropZone); 
            FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles(); 
            // step through each found file 
            foreach (FileInfo fiTemp in fi) 
            { 
                //    Connection String to Excel Workbook 
                string excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + DropZone + "\\" + fiTemp + "'; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;\""; 
                string SheetName = string.Empty; 
                //    Create Connection to Excel Workbook 
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr)) 
                { 
                    try 
                    { 
                        string curaddy2 = string.Empty; 
                        string priaddy2 = string.Empty; 
                        connection.Open(); 
                        DataTable dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null); 
                        if (dt != null) 
                        { 
                            string[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count]; 
                            int i = 0; 
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
                            { 
                                excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();                                     
                                #region ExcelReading 
                                SheetName = excelSheets[i].ToString(); 
                                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip] FROM '" + SheetName.ToString() + "'", connection); 
                                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                                { 
                                    // SQL Server Connection String 

                                    string sqlConnectionString = DBUtils.DBString; 
                                    // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
                                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString)) 
                                    { 
                    // Columns get copied from sheet and into bulk copy statement 
                                        logger.MyLogFile("" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Bulk Copy: ", "ID Number " + dr.GetValue(0).ToString() + ""); 
                                        // now that matrix is created, do the insert 
                                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Table"; 
                                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr); 
                                        logger.MyLogFile("" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Bulk Copy: ", "All values inserted as burst"); 
                                    } 
                                } 
                                #endregion 
                                i++; 
                            } 
                        } 
                        dt.Dispose(); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception ex) 
                    { 
                        logger.MyLogFile("" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Importer \n", "Import failed, error code: " + ex.ToString() + ""); 
                    }                         
                    finally 
                    {                             
                        connection.Close(); 
                    } 
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `excelSheets` have names with `$` sign? If not trying changing: `OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip] FROM '" + SheetName.ToString() + "'", connection);`
to:

`OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip] FROM [" + SheetName.ToString() + "$]", connection);`

For some reason spreadsheet names are concatenated with `$`. I was stuck on this some time ago and it helped me.

Comment: Well, the exact error I am getting is this:

10/23/2014 8:32:06 AM Importer 
Import failed, error code: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): No value given for one or more required parameters.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at ...

Comment: It is providing me with the $ at the end of the sheet name.

Comment: The query is Select * FROM [" + SheetName.ToString() + "]

Comment: Change: `OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip] FROM '" + SheetName.ToString() + "'", connection);` to `string xls_query = "SELECT [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip] FROM '" + SheetName.ToString() + "'"; OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(xls_query, connection);` and show me what the value in `xls_query`

Comment: Ok, the value came out to be

Select * FROM "[AGE$]"

Comment: Try again, but without quote marks. What that error exactly states?

Comment: The odd thing is it said there were no rows. Let me keep tinkering with it until I get a meaningful error.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed that problem but now I have another one. Using SQL Bulk Copy, I must not be specifying the sheet column name correctly: This ends up empty:

bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[First Name]", "[First Name]");